# How to Use Load Data .dat from Matlab in VB.NET with DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, matlab

How can I load a data in VB.NET for Matlab?

In example I have a code in matlab like this

```
x = load('ex2x.dat');
```

Then how can I change the data with DataGridView in VB.NET? The concept is like this :

```
x = load("datagridview's column data values");
```

Please help me.

Comment: Well, Stackoverflow's masters now is arrogant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> Imports System.IO Public Class Form1 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal
> sender As System.Object, _ ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles
> Button1.Click
>         Dim readStream As FileStream
>         Dim msg As String
>         Try readStream = New FileStream("c:\testBinary.dat", FileMode.Open)
>             Dim readBinary As New BinaryReader(readStream)
>             msg = readBinary.ReadString()
>             MsgBox(msg)
>             readStream.Close()
>         Catch ex As Exception
>             MsgBox(ex.ToString)
>         End Try
>     End Sub End Class
```

use above code it will help full for you

Comment: Thanks, you are kind stackoverflow's people. :)